# Call a class with append that targets class variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = ["baz", "qux", "quux", "quuz", "corge", "grault", "garply", "waldo", "fred", "plugh", "xyzzy", "thud"]
```

How can I call `Foo().append()` that appends to `Foo().bar`?

Ex:

```py
x = Foo()

x.append("asd")

# What I want to happen:
# self.bar now is [..., "asd"]

# What actually happens:
# AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Just write a function `append` in Foo that wraps the call to self.bar.append

Comment: I need some sleep.

Comment: `x.bar.append("asd")` should work. Just tested and did not add to Class variable bar.

Comment: You could do the following in the constructor self.append = self.bar.append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an `append` function myself:

```py
# ... in the Foo() class

    def append(self, value):
        return self.bar.append(value)
```

Edit: A simpler method that would also work

```py
# ... in Foo().__init__(self)
    self.append = self.bar.append
```

(Thank you @RaySteam)

Comment: IMHO this would not be considered a `Pythonic` expression. If you want to follow standards that `bar` is an internal variable that other users shouldn't use (and so therefore would need 'getters and setters' like other languages), then call it `_bar`

Answer (score 0):

You could set `self.append` in the `__init__` function:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = ["baz", "qux", "quux", "quuz", "corge", "grault", "garply", "waldo", "fred", "plugh", "xyzzy", "thud"]
        self.append = self.bar.append
```

Then call it as expected:

```
x = Foo()
x.append("asd")
print(x.bar)
#[..., "asd"]
```

Although why not just subclass `list` if this is the goal?

```
class Foo(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.extend(["baz", "qux", "quux", "quuz", "corge", "grault", "garply", "waldo", "fred", "plugh", "xyzzy", "thud"])

f = Foo()
f.append('asd')
print(f)
#[..., "asd"]
```